# Swift: cannot convert protocol constrained to type to value of that type

Tags: swift, casting, constraints, protocols

I am trying to constrain the input to a method to a list of instances conforming to a specific protocol. In my particular case I do not have control over the method and cannot change its arguments. The method takes an array of a specific type as input. I was thinking I could make a protocol constrained to that type and then pass in an array of instance conforming to that protocol. But the compiler won't let me.

Why can't I do the following ?

```
protocol SomeProtocol where Self: SomeClass {

}

class SomeClass: SomeProtocol {

}

func doSomething(input: [SomeClass]) {

}

let someClasses: [SomeProtocol] = [SomeClass(), SomeClass()]

// Cannot convert value of type '[SomeProtocol]' to expected argument type '[SomeClass]'
doSomething(input: someClasses)
```

Comment: What is the point of using a protocol in the first place. The things that you showed you want to do can be done without the protocol.

Comment: `[SomeProtocol]` is a superset of `[SomeClass]`, there is no way the compiler can statically verify you're actually passing an argument of the correct type. You're saying 'here are a bunch of `SomeProtocols` but the expected argument is a bunch of `SomeClass`es. This is a type mismatch.

Comment: You may be thinking this should work because your array contains `SomeClass` but the compiler checks the compile-time type of the argument, not the runtime type of its contents. It doesn't care what you put in that array, as long as it's a subtype of `SomeProtocol`. The type of `someClasses` is [`SomeProtocol`] whatever subtype of `SomeProtocol` you put in there. Your function call though specifically expects `[SomeClass]`, a type more specific than the one you're passing in.

Comment: @pvg Thank you for your reply, but I was thinking the where clause on the protocol should tell the compiler that even though the array is typed as `[SomeProtocol]` it can only ever contain `SomeClass` ?

Comment: I believe that constraint check is only applied when the protocol is adopted. It doesn't define a broader type relationship.

Comment: Ah that would make sense and explain why what I am trying to do would not work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`doSomething`'s `input` is an `[SomeClass]` but you are passing a `[SomeProtocol]` to it. `SomeProtocol` is not a `SomeClass` but `SomeClass` is a `SomeProtocol`. To satisfy the compiler, you just have to change the type of `someClasses` to `[SomeClass]`:

```
let someClasses = [SomeClass(), SomeClass()]
```

Or you could change the requirement of the parameter:

```
func doSomething(input: [SomeProtocol])
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is in my concrete example I cannot change the requirement of the parameter for doSomething as I do not own the implementation. My code example is just to highlight the general issue, in my real world scenario I am using the protocol to constrain someClasses. I guess I am just trying to understand why constraining `SomeProtocol` to `SomeClass`with the `where` clause does not work.